# The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, types, progress-bar, percentage

I have written TypeScript code to calculate the percentages of firms and insights and show them in a progress bar. The code is presented below:

```js
export class InsightsComponent implements OnInit {
  insights: any;
  firm: Firm;

  constructor(
    private firmService: FirmService,
    private provider: FirmProvider,
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.provider.getInsights(this.firmService.getDomain())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.insights = data;
      });
    this.provider.getCurrent(this.firmService.getDomain())
      .then(data => {
        this.firm = data;
      });
  }

  calcInvoiced = (firm: Firm, insights: number) => {
    ((this.firm / this.insights) * 100).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

Could you provide me with any feedback on how to optimize and improve this code?

Comment: Can you please explain what is a `firm` and what is an `insight` so that we can better understand the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your arithmetic operation to a variable, or at least return the result.

```
    calcInvoiced = (firm: Firm, insights: number) => {
         return ((this.firm / this.insights) * 100).toFixed(2);
  }
```

`this.firm / this.insights` will also be a problem because this.firm is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have different options to simplify your code:

1. If variables "insights" and "firm" are not needed, but only the derived value is, you could define a new promise and use it in your template by using the `async` operator like this. This will lead to a one time calculation on init.

```
invoiced = Promise.all([
  this.provider.getInsights(this.firmService.getDomain()),
  this.provider.getCurrent(this.firmService.getDomain()),
]).then(([insights, firm]) => ((firm / insights) * 100).toFixed(2));
```

2. If the other variables are also needed, I suggest you to return the observables from the service directly, store them in properties and use the `combineLatest` operator from rxjs (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) in order to dervice the `invoiced` variable. You can also consume these values then with the `async` pipe.